# How to get a single outcome from each python unit-test module

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have different unit_test modules which are included by unit test codes as you'll see:

```py
    import unittest

    class TestTest(unittest.TestCase):
        def setUp(self):
            pass

        def tearDown(self):
            pass

        def test_type(self):
            self.assertTrue(False)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        unittest.main()
```

I need to get the result of each module after running it and write it in the database. So I expect 3 different outcomes after running each module:

- PASSED
- NOTPASSED
- WORKING

But the problem is after running the test module I get such a output.

> F
>       ======================================================================
>       FAIL: test_test (**main**.TestTest)
>       ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/Users/~/mytest.py", line 12, in test_test
>           self.assertTrue(False)
>       AssertionError: False is not true

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

I don't know if there is something in unittest to give me a straight value as I expect?

I also tried this:

```py
    TestTest = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestTest)
    suit = unittest.TestSuite([TestTest])
    result = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suit)

    print(result)
```

But it gives me this:

> test_test (**main**.TestTest) ... FAIL

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_test (__main__.TestTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/~/mytest.py", line 12, in test_test
    self.assertTrue(False)
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestResult

Comment: what's the difference between `WORKING` and `PASSED` state?

Answer (score 1):

Basically if you need in your test results more information just add the keyword `msg` documenting the test, for example:

```
self.assertTrue(False, msg = 'Host connection not stablished.')
```

Comment: I don't need more information, I just need status of each module after being compiled. something like OK, Failed, WORKING

Comment: when you run this it will automatically come "ok" or "Failure" in status. Not sure about "working"

Comment: Why don't you just print it inside the test?